# Read json array in request body of express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in express.js framework. I have problem in getting value of array key in req.body. Following is the data which I want to parse.Please suggest how I can get uploaded_id_images in req.body

```
name: 'test',
  age: '18',
  sex: 'M',
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  password: '1234567',
  'uploaded_id_images[]':
   [ '1567658464055_download (5).jpeg',
     '1567658464057_download (6).jpeg' ],
  'uploaded_user_photos[]':
   [ '1567658455144_download (3).jpeg',
     '1567658455145_download (4).jpeg',
     '1567658455145_download (5).jpeg' ] }
```

Comment: Assuming that you parsed the JSON body into a JS object `obj` then it should be `obj['uploaded_id_images[]']`.

Comment: 'uploaded_id_images[]' should be converted to ```uploaded_id_images[]``` (without the quotation marks) as it is a key not a value.